# Zend Form isValid() return false

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

My Zend Form `isValid()` method is return false even though there is no errors showing in anywhere. Because of that i cannot execute the `isValid()` method and store my form value into mysql. I have no idea why it will return false when there is no errors.

My Controller:

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    private $usersTable;

    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }

    public function addAction()
    {
        $form = new Add();

        if($this->request->isPost())
        {
            $complaintPost = new Post();
            $form->bind($complaintPost);
            $form->setInputFilter(new AddPost());
            $form->setData($this->request->getPost());
            $a = 'apple';
            $b = 'boy';
            if($form->isValid()) // Check whether it is running or not 
            {
              echo "<script>console.log($a);</script>";
              $complaintPost = $form->getData();
              //"<script>console.log($this->getUsersTable()->insert($data));</script>";
              $this->getUsersTable()->insert($complaintPost); //checking whether is it null
            }
            else
            {
              echo "<script>console.log($form->isValid());</script>";
            }
        }

        return new ViewModel(array(
                'form' => $form,
                ));
    }

    public function getUsersTable()
    {
        if(!$this->usersTable)
        {
            $this->usersTable = new TableGateway(
                    'complaint',
                 $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')
            );
        }
        return $this->usersTable;
    }

}
```

My phtml file:

```
<h1>Add Complaint</h1>

<?php
/** @var \Zend\Form\Form $form */
    $form = $this->form;
    $form->prepare();
    echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
?> 

<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('name'));?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('icno'));?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('address'));?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('phoneno'));?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('complaintdetail'));?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('datetime'));?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('image'));?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('location'));?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('remarks'));?>
</div>

<?php echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));?>
<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag();?>
```

My form:

```
class Add extends Form 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct('add');
        $this->setHydrator(new ClassMethods());

        //More to add
        $name = new Element\Text('name');
        $name->setLabel("Name");
        $name->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');

        $nric = new Element\Text('icno');
        $nric->setLabel("NRIC");
        $nric->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');

        $address = new Element\Text('address');
        $address->setLabel("Address");
        $address->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');

        $phonenum = new Element\Text('phoneno');
        $phonenum->setLabel("Phone Number");
        $phonenum->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');

        $complaintdetail = new Element\Text('complaintdetail');
        $complaintdetail->setLabel("Things to Complaint");
        $complaintdetail->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');

        $dateHappen = new Element\Text('datetime');
        $dateHappen->setLabel("Date and time");
        $dateHappen->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');

        $picture = new Element\File('image');
        $picture->setLabel('Photo');
        $picture->setAttribute('id', 'image');

        $location = new Element\Text('location');
        $location->setLabel("Location");
        $location->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');

        $remarks = new Element\Text('remarks');
        $remarks->setLabel("Remarks");
        $remarks->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');

        $submit = new Element\Submit('submit');
        $submit->setValue('Sent Complaint');
        $submit->setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary');

        $this->add($name);
        $this->add($nric);
        $this->add($address);
        $this->add($phonenum);
        $this->add($complaintdetail);
        $this->add($dateHappen);
        $this->add($picture);
        $this->add($location);
        $this->add($remarks);
        $this->add($submit);
    }
}
```

My Form Validator:

```
class AddPost extends InputFilter
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $name = new Input('name');
        $name->setRequired(true);
        $name->setValidatorChain($this->getNameValidatorChain());
        $name->setFilterChain($this->getStringTrimFilterChain());

        $nric = new Input('icno');
        $nric->setRequired(true);
        $nric->setValidatorChain($this->getICValidatorChain());
        $nric->setFilterChain($this->getStringTrimFilterChain());

        $address = new Input('address');
        $address->setRequired(true);
        $address->setValidatorChain($this->getAddressValidatorChain());
        $address->setFilterChain($this->getStringTrimFilterChain());

        $phonenum = new Input('phoneno');
        $phonenum->setRequired(true);
        $phonenum->setValidatorChain($this->getPhoneValidatorChain());
        $phonenum->setFilterChain($this->getStringTrimFilterChain());

        $complaintdetail = new Input('complaintdetail');
        $complaintdetail->setRequired(true);
        $complaintdetail->setValidatorChain($this->getComplaintValidatorChain());
        $complaintdetail->setFilterChain($this->getStringTrimFilterChain());

        $datetime = new Input('datetime');
        $datetime->setRequired(true);
        $datetime->setFilterChain($this->getStringTrimFilterChain());

        $picture = new Input('image');
        $picture->setRequired(true);

        $location = new Input('location');
        $location->setRequired(true);
        $location->setValidatorChain($this->getLocationValidatorChain());
        $location->setFilterChain($this->getStringTrimFilterChain());

        $remark = new Input('remarks');
        $remark->setRequired(true);
        $remark->setValidatorChain($this->getICValidatorChain());
        $remark->setFilterChain($this->getStringTrimFilterChain());

        $this->add($name);
        $this->add($nric);
        $this->add($address);
        $this->add($phonenum);
        $this->add($complaintdetail);
        $this->add($datetime);
        $this->add($picture);
        $this->add($location);
        $this->add($remark);
    }

    protected function getStringTrimFilterChain() 
    {
        $filterChain = new FilterChain();
        $filterChain->attach(new StringTrim());

        return $filterChain;
    }

    protected function getLocationValidatorChain()
    {
        $stringLength = new StringLength();
        $stringLength->setMin(3);
        $stringLength->setMax(100);

        $validatorChain = new ValidatorChain();
        $validatorChain->attach(new Alnum(true));
        $validatorChain->attach($stringLength);

        return $validatorChain;
    }

    protected function getComplaintValidatorChain()
    {
        $stringLength = new StringLength();
        $stringLength->setMin(3);
        $stringLength->setMax(100);

        $validatorChain = new ValidatorChain();
        $validatorChain->attach(new Alnum(true));
        $validatorChain->attach($stringLength);

        return $validatorChain;
    }

    protected function getPhoneValidatorChain()
    {
        $stringLength = new StringLength();
        $stringLength->setMin(3);
        $stringLength->setMax(15);

        $validatorChain = new ValidatorChain();
        $validatorChain->attach(new Alnum(true));
        $validatorChain->attach($stringLength);

        return $validatorChain;
    }

    protected function getAddressValidatorChain() 
    {
        $stringLength = new StringLength();
        $stringLength->setMin(3);
        $stringLength->setMax(70);

        $validatorChain = new ValidatorChain();
        $validatorChain->attach(new Alnum(true));
        $validatorChain->attach($stringLength);

        return $validatorChain;
    }

    protected function getICValidatorChain() 
    {
        $stringLength = new StringLength();
        $stringLength->setMin(3);
        $stringLength->setMax(50);

        $validatorChain = new ValidatorChain();
        $validatorChain->attach(new Alnum(true));
        $validatorChain->attach($stringLength);

        return $validatorChain;
    }

    protected function getNameValidatorChain()
    {
        $stringLength = new StringLength();
        $stringLength->setMin(3);
        $stringLength->setMax(50);

        $validatorChain = new ValidatorChain();
        $validatorChain->attach(new Alpha(true));
        $validatorChain->attach($stringLength);

        return $validatorChain;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read [the documentation on the Zend-Framework input-filter class](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.input-filter.intro.html) you can see that you have to get the messages yourself from the input-filter class after checking invalid:

```
if ($inputFilter->isValid()) {
    echo "The form is valid\n";
} else {
    echo "The form is not valid\n";
    foreach ($inputFilter->getInvalidInput() as $error) {
        print_r($error->getMessages());
    }
}
```

So to see the validation error messages you need to get those messages and output them yourself in some way. Most likely you would attach them to a response object and return them to the client in some orderly way.

Comment: The error message should show you what is wrong with the file. It could be too big, wrong file type, or something else could have gone wrong while uploading the file.

Comment: I have try with the above code to check for the form valid. I insert all the value in the form and click submit button but it still state that my value isEmpty like below:

Comment: The form is not valid Array ( [isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty ) Array ( [isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty ) Array ( [isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty ) Array ( [isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty ) Array ( [isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty ) Array ( [isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty ) Array ( [isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty ) Array ( [isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty ) Array ( [isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty )

Comment: Yes, so those fields are not allowed to be empty. It is clearly stated in those messages what the problem is.

Comment: Your question was *"I have no idea why it will return false when there is no errors"*. I answered your question, and as you can see in that messages array you clearly have errors in your validators. I suggest you accept my answer. Most likely you go wrong here: `$complaintPost = new Post(); $form->bind($complaintPost);`. You bind a new empty object instead of the post data from your request object...

Comment: i have fill up all the field in my form but still got this error.

Comment: I suggest you read [the documentation here](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#validating-forms). Check also the contents of your request object (does it contain post data?)

Comment: I have check the content of request object the value i enter in the form is return and why it still showing the form is not valid?

Comment: Getting same issue "isValid in zend framework form returns FALSE" in zend framework 3 version. I have login screen with email, password and csrf fields on form. Kindly suggest me how to fix this issue.